# strcat() could not concatenate

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcat

I have a two-dimensional character array to be concatenated into an array. It has an error:

> error C2664: 'strcat' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *[80]' to 'char *'

Here's the code:

```
char *article[5] = {"the", "a", "one", "some", "any"};
char *sentence[80];

num = rand() % 5;
for(int x = 0; x < strlen(article[num]); x++){
    strcat(sentence, article[num][x]);    //a random element will be concatinated to the sentence array
}
```

Comment: change `char *sentence[80]` to `char sentence[80]`

Comment: and you don't need the for loop....  `strcat(sentence, article[num])` should be sufficient as `strcat` copies the entire string over.

Comment: i tried what you suggested, but it shows some strange characters, not the char from the article array.

Comment: You can't concatenate onto an ASCIIZ string that doesn't exist, and in your code you've left `sentence` uninitialised so it doesn't contain an ASCIIZ string and is illegal to read from: that's not a suitable precondition for using `strcat`.  Try `char sentence[80] = { '\0' };` or add `sentence[0] = '\0';` between the definition of `sentence` and the `strcat`.  I'm not sure what yuo're trying to do with the loop: did you mean to randomly pick an article to concatenate, then concatenate another article, until you'd concatenated 5?

Comment: @TonyD yes, initializing worked. yes you're right, i am concatenating random article until i get 5. but the loop here enables to display all characters in a single index, if i remove the loop, it'll just concatenate the first letter of the word.

Comment: @chrisjohn016: *"if i remove the loop, it'll just concatenate the first letter of the word."* - not after you remove the `[x]` bit so it'll compile, because [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) only works when the second argument is a `const char*` to an ASCIIZ string - it won't accept a single character as you tried to get by picking `[x]` from the selected article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some fixed up code that might do what you want, but it's hard to tell what you want for sure...

```
srand(time_t(0));  // seed the random number generate once

// use const when handling pointers to string literals
const char* article[5] = {"the", "a", "one", "some", "any"};

char sentence[80];  // 80 character buffer in automatic storage - no pointers
sentence[0] = '\0'; // empty ASCIIZ string to start

for (int x = 0; x < 5; ++x)
{
    int num = rand() % 5;

    strcat(sentence, article[num]);
}
printf("%s\n", sentence);
```

Comment: It's probably worth adding a `strcat(sentence, " ");` as well for the benefit of output formatting.

Comment: Last question, how do I make the first letter of the first word toUpper with this?

Comment: @chrisjohn016 `sentence[0] = toupper(sentence[0]));` But things like that are easily found in online tutorials. No need to ask here and then wait for someone to answer.

Comment: @MrLister yes i know it is in the tutorials. but i mean, how do I make the first letter toUpper() is I wanted to make the first letter of every word toUpper? because sentence[0] = toupper(sentence[0])); capitalizes only the first letter of the first word..

Comment: @chrisjohn016: the easiest way is obviously to change `article`'s string literals, next easiest may be to record the current end-of-string position (where the NUL terminator is) with `const char* p_nul = sentence + strlen(sentence);` before you call `strcat`, then after `strcat` use `*p_nul = toupper(*p_nul);` to overwrite the character newly placed there with its uppercase version. That's a little inefficient (calling `strlen` repeatedly), but it's unlikely to matter unless you're handling millions of long strings.

Comment: @chrisjohn016 That is a different question than the one you asked, and I believe you should ask a new question for that.

Comment: FWIW - an efficient alternative is to first copy just the uppercased first letter, then `strcat` the rest of the article: `const char* p_nul = sentence + strlen(sentence); *p_nul = toupper(article[n][0]); *++p_nul = '\0'; strcat(p_nul, &article[num][1]);`.  But do note that the way you're using `strcat()` is very inefficient anyway, as it keeps re-scanning the earlier parts of `sentence` to work out where it should append the next string.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your definition for sentence.  The code that you are using, char *sentence[80] is defining a pointer to an array of 80 string pointers.  Don't use the * qualifier.  Here's some code:

```
#define MAX_ARRAY 5
#define MAX_SENTENCE 80

char *article[MAX_ARRAY] = {"the", "a", "one", "some", "any"};
char sentence[MAX_SENTENCE];
int num;

num = rand() % MAX_ARRAY
strncat(sentence, article[num], MAX_SENTENCE - 1);
sentence[MAX_SENTENCE - 1] = 0x00;
```

Notice that I use strncat instead of strcat.  Although your code as posted will not overflow the buffer, with today's magnitude of code reuse, it's always good practice to check the size of the destination so you don't introduce a security vulnerability.